# Finding error after publish my asp.net web application on Godaddy

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string

I have already publish my web application but i am facing an error i tried a lot to fix it and i search a lot on web but i couldnt fix it, so please could you help me to fix this issue.

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="BeravaConnectionString"
     connectionString="Data Source=156.74.335.445; User ID=varooo; database = betop; Password:Sdvavava"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 118.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Format of the
>   initialization string does not conform to specification starting at
>   index 118.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not
>   conform to specification starting at index 118.]
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String
>   connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean
>   useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) +5360365
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable
>   parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +124
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString,
>   Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +95
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String
>   connectionString) +59
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String
>   connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +24
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions&
>   userConnectionOptions) +167
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key) +61
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>   +66    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString, SqlCredential credential) +26
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) +6 
>   beravoSV.Berava.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +311
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +51    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +772

Comment: You've given very little information.  You can't do anything with an error and no code.  Post the relevant portion of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should be `Password=Sdvavava`, instead of `Password:Sdvavava`. Use an equals sign instead of a colon, like the other parameters.